# How to include css/javascript/php-includes file in subdomain from domain

Tags: php, html

I want to use css, javascript, php-includes from main domain into sub-domain.

Directory structure for main domain.

```
/root/global/css/css.css
/root/global/javascript/javascript.js
/root/global/include/include.php
```

Directory structure for sub-domain

```
/root/sub-domain/index.php
```

Now css, javascript, php-includes are not working in sub-domain, i.e I get un-stylized page and no javascript, php files are included.

I am doing this way in sub-domain index.php

```
<link href="../global/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../global/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../global/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

this is not working for sub-domain but working for other same level directories, I also tried this way

```
<link href="http://www.mysite.com/global/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/global/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/global/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

It is also not working for sub-domain but working for other directories in same level.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: try the absolute declaration with http:// prefix

Comment: That won't work to include the script itself, unless you are an RFI victim.

Comment: Open view source in your browser and click the css and js files.

Comment: @x4rf41 I am using absolute declaration.

Comment: Are these included files on the same server? If they are not in the same root directory (e.g. public_html) as your script, then you need to adjust your include path. If you are able to include() a script using a URL, you ARE going to fall victim to an RFI.

Comment: No i am not able to include script using url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough `www.mysite.com/global/css/css.css` looks like an absolute link, in fact it isn't.
If you are on `www.mydomain.com` it will look for `http://www.mydomain.com/www.mysite.com/global/css/css.css` which is what you do not want.

To absolute link resources include the scheme (which would be `http://www.mysite.com/global/...`) or set absolute paths with the trailing slash: `/global/css/css.css`.

Comment: not working either way, I get a warning `No such file` and a Fatal error `Failed opening required `, and no surce code for the page when tring to view source code.

Comment: What I forgot to mention: This only works for CSS/JS. PHP is loading files totally different - you will have to adjust the include path for PHP with `set_include_path` as @L0j1k mentioned OR include the absolute file path. Which will look something like `include '/root/global/include/include.php';`

Comment: Ok. I guess you're doing something really wrong. Any chance to show the real source code, live system?

Comment: things are woorking for css and javascript when trying this way only `http://www.mysite.com/global/css/css.css`

Comment: Not working when trying this way `../global/css/css.css` or `/global/css/css.css`

Comment: Can you tell me why css and javascript can be only linked this way `http://www.mysite.com/global/css/css.css` insted of this `../global/css/css.css`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25081/discussion-between-genesys-and-tall-boy)

Answer (score 1):

For sub-domains, this is working without issues, otherwise, you would have another issue within your files location :

```
src="//www.yourdomain.com/whateverpath/yourfile.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options, you can set the "include path" in the php.ini file, or you can use `set_include_path()` function at the beginning of your script: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php